# How to query and display an aggregatedlist SOQL Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, relationships, count

I'm a complete newbie at salesforce and have spent hours trying to figure this out with no luck (so far)!

The schema is fairly simple: (Objects are bold)

There are **Teachers** (contact record types) that teach **Courses** which **Students** (contact record types) can enroll (**Enrollment**) on.

I need to display the following:

A list of all Courses | The teachers (Courses can only have 1 teacher) | The number of Students enrolled on that course.

ANY help with the query and/or displaying the aggregated result on a visualforce page will be highly appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: Tried normal SQL but obviously that didn't work out so well. Found SOQL trail and completed that which solved that part of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answer (Javier)

After some research I realised there was a trail on SOQL which I completed and was able to get the results I wanted. I also found the method of displaying aggregated results from a blog.

Below the apex page tag

```
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! newEnrollments}" var="enrollment">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:commandLink action="{!enrollment['corses']}" 
                                  value=" {!enrollment['corses']}" /> 

            </apex:column>
```

Difference is of bracket notation rather than dot notation which would've been enrollment.corses in my case.

Note: Headings for results can be displayed through entering the following under the apex column tag:

```
 <apex:facet name="header"></apex:facet>
```

Hopefully this helps someone as it took me quite a while to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you haven't mentioned the exact data model, I'll assume enrollment is an intermediate table that connects students with courses in a M-N relationship.

Given that, you can do something like this to obtain data from each of the tables:

```
SELECT Id, (SELECT Id, Student__r.Name FROM Enrollments__r) FROM Course__c
```

And in case you want to aggregate something, just fit in a COUNT or GROUP BY  with any changes to fit in.